# Python 3D распознавание лиц, классификатор

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, распознавание, классификация, sklearn

Делаю распознавание лиц с помощью 3D камеры, хотел бы узнать как лучше сделать.

Этап 1(готово):

[image: Этап 1]

Что имеем на выходе этого алгоритма - массив из 68 точек с координатами x y z.
Расположение точек:

[image: Шаблон лица]

Значения для каждой точки(для моего лица):

```
lst = {"chin": [
                [-2.813246,  2.586562, 75.5]
                [-2.700682,  0.491332, 75.8]
                [-2.566741, -1.484425, 75.5]
                [-1.896225, -3.48198 , 73.4]
                [-0.814462, -5.139933, 73.1]
                [ 0.492087, -6.846219, 72.2]
                [ 2.331827, -7.985987, 70.8]
                [ 4.362413, -8.810762, 69.9]
                [ 6.421616, -8.884553, 68.8]
                [ 8.443289, -8.547305, 68.8]
                [ 9.788915, -7.595778, 70.4]
                [10.915502, -6.152379, 70.9]
                [11.640747, -4.468151, 71.8]
                [12.176354, -2.628056, 73.0]
                [12.618774, -0.85267 , 74.1]
                [12.856864,  0.984142, 75.5]
                [12.982366,  2.68839 , 74.9]],

        "left eyebrows": [
                [-0.213021,  4.786075, 71.4]
                [ 0.814059,  5.787794, 69.4]
                [ 2.153641,  6.179164, 68.8]
                [ 3.731469,  6.075566, 68.9]
                [ 5.193688,  5.737828, 68.9]],

        "right chin": [
                [ 7.454058,  5.633413, 69. ]
                [ 8.580474,  6.084383, 69. ]
                [ 9.84757 ,  6.286939, 69.9]
                [10.976998,  5.946022, 71.3]
                [11.954364,  4.893176, 73.1]],

        "nose": [
                [ 6.224007,  4.399612, 69.0]
                [ 6.374947,  3.232688, 68.3]
                [ 6.501342,  2.195673, 67.2]
                [ 6.532621,  1.082996, 66.5]
                [ 5.080618, -0.554271, 67.4]
                [ 5.715243, -0.661442, 67.1]
                [ 6.591562, -0.77108 , 67.1]
                [ 7.171181, -0.664399, 67.4]
                [ 7.912693, -0.337483, 68.0]],

        "left eyes": [
                [ 1.499108,  3.754496, 69.7]
                [ 2.289011,  4.31152 , 69.4]
                [ 3.210473,  4.330131, 69.8]
                [ 4.008106,  3.759883, 69.8]
                [ 3.210473,  3.645833, 69.8]
                [ 2.292305,  3.521663, 69.5]],

        "right eyes": [
                [ 7.996273,  3.759883, 69.8]
                [ 8.907853,  4.444181, 69.8]
                [ 9.761106,  4.354946, 70.2]
                [ 9.538014,  3.813749, 70.8]
                [10.77501 ,  3.557082, 70.3]
                [11.958901,  3.666726, 70.2]],

        "mouth": [
                [ 3.870292, -3.858119, 67.4]
                [ 4.955838, -2.968259, 67.1]
                [ 6.05287 , -2.419251, 67.1]
                [ 6.621033, -2.646708, 67.4]
                [ 7.181821, -2.540343, 67.5]
                [ 8.123092, -2.892486, 68.0]
                [ 8.939422, -3.686439, 68.3]
                [ 8.111147, -4.10863 , 67.9]
                [ 7.302816, -4.200932, 67.6]
                [ 6.630856, -4.194718, 67.5]
                [ 5.960855, -4.188504, 67.4]
                [ 4.955838, -4.176075, 67.1]],

        "lips": [
                [ 4.304015, -3.852394, 67.2]
                [ 5.969699, -3.312385, 67.5]
                [ 6.650503, -3.322199, 67.6]
                [ 7.2031  , -3.322199, 67.6]
                [ 8.468555, -3.564372, 68.0]
                [ 7.2031  , -3.211581, 67.6]
                [ 6.650503, -3.322199, 67.6]
                [ 5.859506, -3.312385, 67.5]]}
```

Этап 2(не готово).
Моя идея заключалась в том чтобы взять евклидово расстояние между основными точками и записать их в массив, т.е. взять расстояние между глазами, между носом и ртом, и прочее. Всего получилось 110 расстояний между разными точками. Дальше отслеживал угол поворота/наклона головы и делал для каждого лица 5 подклассов для каждого из углов, записывал туда все 110 расстояний и получал датасет.
Потом я используя

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

def get_predict(self, input_data):
    for i in input_data:
        for k in self.dataset:
            res = sum(sum((a - b) ** 2 for a, b in zip(row, i)) / len(self.dataset[k])
                      for row in self.dataset[k]) ** 0.5
            print(k, res)
```

Пытался считать что-то типа среднеквадратичного отклонения и берать от него корень, чтобы размерность сохранить. По сути на этом всё должно было закончится и программа работала бы, но... данные оказались слишком похожими и точность моей "нейронной сети" по распознаванию лиц допускала ошибки в 15-30% случаев. Но работала что уже радует.

А теперь главный вопрос. Что я могу сделать с массивом из 68 точек, чтобы лица разных людей различались как можно больше.
Единственно что я сейчас придумал, это брать например центр носа за начало оси, и считать глубину по оси Z до всех остальных точек.

Answer (score 1):

Ответа точного я вам не дам, потому как распознаванием лиц (самостоятельным, а не на готовых сетках) занимаются целые коллективы ученых, ищут эти самые закономерности и пр. Одно могу сказать -  я часто очень негативно высказываюсь к попыткам применить нейросеть где не попадя, исходя из соображения "модности". Но вот есть задачи, в которых действительно именно нейросети являются наиболее разумным методом решения. И распознавание лиц (изображений вообще) -  это одна из таких задач. Потому что я могу сейчас нафантазировать, например, сравнивать овалы лица, расстояния между нижней (или верхней) точкой нижней губы и нижней точкой подбородка, или левого края правого глаза относительно правого края носа.... Но нейросеть именно тем и хороша, что пытается сама найти такие значимые закономерности.

Так что если это не просто учебный проект, то скорее всего рано или поздно вы придёте к тому, что начете строить настоящую нейросеть, а потом -  переоткроете те сети, которые уже имеются в наличии.

Но если проект учебный - то фантазируйте: ширина носа, отношение ширины носа к толщине губ, разрез глаз (отношение высоты к ширине) и т.д.